# Cherrypy: set delay between two threads

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, cherrypy

Good morning. I have a restful API application with cherrypy. Data that arrives from a webpage is sent to a database. My application sets IDs using an internal variable. It is a kind of counter. When the webpage sends more than one file sometimes happens that updating the counter of IDs is slower than files so i set the same id for two files. I want to set a little delay (more than 5ms) between a thread and the next one, so that i avoid this problem. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to update the counter under a **lock synch primitive** and not by adding a delay.
You will need to create a lock that will be shared by all threads

`shared_lock = threading.Lock()`.

Each Thread should increment the counter by:

```
with shared_lock :
    # increment your conter
```

Comment: So i should write shared_lock in the init method so that every thread could "see" it and the "with part" when i have to increase my counter am i right?

Comment: I don't know how your code is looking so i am not sure. But you need to define the lock in context that all thread "sees".